# Horns in animals and birds

Tags: zoology, anatomy

Are there any carnivores with horns (whether extinct or currently alive)?

Do any flying creatures have horns?

By horns I mean horn like structure.

Comment: Why do you want to know, and what do you know from before? Are you aware of the distinction between e.g. horns and anthers (and other types of hornlike structures)? What types you include as "horns" make a big difference to your question.

Comment: honestly, @OneFace this is a bit of a 'let me google that for you' question :)   http://lmgtfy.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Males of the carnivorous [Jackson's chameleon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson%27s_chameleon) (*Trioceros jacksonii*) have three hornlike structures on their heads (also found in a couple of related species). From what I know, these are true horns, which means that they are pointed keratin-covered protrusions that have a core of living bone, see e.g. [this](http://www.torontozoo.com/ExploretheZoo/AnimalDetails.asp?pg=794) website from Toronto Zoo ([this](http://reptilis.net/lacertilia/chamaeleonidae/bodyplan.html) page also claims that their horns show annual growth rings). However, there are many definitions of horns (some only consider the horns in Artiodactyla to be "true" horns), so you need to be specific in what you are asking for. Used casually, the [antlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antler) of Cervids or other similar structures, are often considered as horns.

[image]

As for birds, the closest thing to a horned bird I can think of are species of the Australian [Cassowary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassowary) (*Casuarius*). They have a bony crest on the top of their heads, which is covered by keratinous skin. However, the bony crest is supposed to be relatively soft and spongy, and can hardly be counted as a horn is the strict sense of the word.

[image]
(Southern cassowary, *Casuarius casuarius*, from Wikipedia)

Answer (score 2):

As far as alive carnivorous land animals go, there are non. But let's search in the sea:

1. Narwhal ([***Monodon monoceros***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narwhal))

   [image]

   <sup>courtesy: http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1625488/images/o-NARWHAL-facebook.jpg</sup>
2. Longhorn cowfish ([***Lactoria cornuta***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longhorn_cowfish))

   [image]

   <sup>courtesy: Wikipedia</sup>

They are omnivourus and feed mainly on microorganism. There are loads of sites claiming them horned puffer fish.

---

**Extinct**

1. Carnotaurus ([***Carnotaurus sastrei***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnotaurus))

   [image]

   <sup>courtesy: https://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141130153854/dinosaurs/images/e/ed/084d14_0ce4968fba228be913b757cc8ba15f88.gif</sup>

---

Horned Flying Bird

1. Gread hornbill ([***Buceros bicornis***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_hornbill))
   [image]

   <sup>courtesy: http://www.livepterosaur.com/LP_Blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Lip-Kee-Malaysia-Hornbill-5110157612_e1e078296f_z.jpg</sup>

Comment: What definition of "horn" are you using? The included examples represents different types of structures with different functions, and several of them are not horns in the strict sense of the word. Based on your examples, you also seem to use such a wide definition of "horn" that your own first sentence is factually incorrect.

Comment: Great horn bills do have a horn shaped bill, but its not a horn.